# list indices must be integers, not str - regular expression

Tags: python, regex, list

I am trying to find all data in a list that ends the word ".torrent". For that I used regular expressions. When I wrote this:

```
for k in link_torrent2:
m=re.findall(r'\S+\.torrent',link_torrent2[k])
if m:
    link2.append(m)
```

I got an error:

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

All code:

```
import re
link2=[]

link_torrent1=[u'#', u'/torrent_download/3797378/THE+BLACKLIST+%282014%29+S02E02+x264+1080p%28WEB-DL%29+eng+NLsubs+TBS.torrent',
    u'/category/581/', u'/torrent/3797378/THE+BLACKLIST+%282014%29+S02E02+x264+1080p%28WEB-DL%29+eng+NLsubs+TBS.html',
    u'/torrent_download/3795431/The+Blacklist+S02E02+720p+HDTV+x264+AAC+-+Ozlem.torrent', u'/category/581/',
    u'/torrent/3795431/The+Blacklist+S02E02+720p+HDTV+x264+AAC+-+Ozlem.html', u'/torrent_download/3795314/The.Blacklist.S02E02.HDTV.x264-ChameE.torrent']
link_torrent2=[str(x) for x in link_torrent1]

print link_torrent1

for k in link_torrent2:
    m=re.findall(r'\S+\.torrent',link_torrent2[k])  ##here shows error
    if m:
        link2.append(m)
print m
```

Comment: The statement must be `m=re.findall(r'\S+\.torrent',k)`

Comment: that's because you used iterator.

Answer (score 2):

`k` is *not an integer*. It is one element from the `link_torrent2` list. Just use it directly:

```
for k in link_torrent2:
    m=re.findall(r'\S+\.torrent', k)
```

That's because Python `for` loops are really [Foreach loops](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop); each iteration the next element from the input iterable (`link_torrent2`) is assigned to your chosen target, `k` in this case.

Rather than use regular expressions, you could just use the [`str.endswith()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
for k in link_torrent2:
    if k.endswith('.torrent'):
        link2.append(m)
```

or, more compact with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
link2 = [k for k in link_torrent2 if k.endswidth('.torrent')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `re.findall` function just `re.search` would be fine.

```
>>> link_torrent2=[str(x) for x in link_torrent1]
>>> [i for i in link_torrent2 if re.search(r'.*\.torrent$', i)]
['/torrent_download/3797378/THE+BLACKLIST+%282014%29+S02E02+x264+1080p%28WEB-DL%29+eng+NLsubs+TBS.torrent', '/torrent_download/3795431/The+Blacklist+S02E02+720p+HDTV+x264+AAC+-+Ozlem.torrent', '/torrent_download/3795314/The.Blacklist.S02E02.HDTV.x264-ChameE.torrent']
```